# How to override the "name" HtmlAttribute of Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.Location, "Location")
    @Html.LabelFor(Model=>Model.Location,"Location")
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model=>Model.Model,"Model")
    @Html.LabelFor(Model=>Model.Model,"Model")
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model=>Model.MovableUnit,"MU")
    @Html.LabelFor(Model=>Model.MovableUnit,"MU")




   <input id="Location" name="Location" type="radio" value="Location" />
    <label for="Location">Location</label>
    <input id="Model" name="Model" type="radio" value="Model" />
    <label for="Model">Model</label>
    <input id="MovableUnit" name="MovableUnit" type="radio" value="MU" />
    <label for="MovableUnit">MU</label>
```

How to have a common name="radiobtn" for all the above Radio buttons?
        The problem is I want to select only one radio button at a time, but in this case all are selectable at the same time.

Comment: @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.Location, "LOC",new { @Name="Location"})
                    
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.Model_Number, "MOD", new { @Name="Location"})

  @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.MovableUnit, "MU", new { @Name="Location"})

Comment: I have three controller parameters Location,Model_Number,MovableUnit.Which one to use as Name attribute??

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just create a dummy property in your Model class like, 
public string Dummy{get; set;}

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.Location, "LOC", new { @Name = "Dummy"})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.Model_Number, "MOD", new { @Name = "Dummy" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.MovableUnit, "MU", new { @Name = "Dummy" })
```

Get the value "LOC", "MOD", "MU" using property name 'Dummy'.

Comment: Note... @Name is case sensitive.

Comment: This works, but it's very hacky. If you check the source, you'll see there are now 2 attributes, "Name" and "name". It's just a browser quirk that "Name" happens to take precedence.

Comment: Having two same attributes means if they ever change how browsers behave, this will stop working or start missbehaving

Answer (score 5):

Use the function without "for", then you can specify the name:

```
@Html.RadioButton("newname", "value", new { @id="oldname" })
```

Comment: I tested it and it works. Make sure you are using `RadioButton(..)` instead of `RadioButtonFor(..)`, and that you are passing a string as the name parameter in the function.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716468/possible-to-change-name-of-radiobuttonfor

Comment: @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.Location, "LOC", new { @Name = "n1" })

                    @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Location, "Location") Doing so for three different radio button,only 1 is selectable but the value is not passed to controller from view.

Comment: Make sure your controller's parameter name matches the name you are giving (`n1`)

Comment: Dude ! But my other Controller parameters are getting the same value.